# Execute C program at bootloader level via Assembler

Tags: c, assembly, bootloader

I wrote a custom (VERY basic "Hello world!") bootloader in Assembler and I would like to execute a C program in that. Would the C program work, or fail due to a lost `stdio.h` file? And how could I bundle the C program along with the bootloader into a single .bin file to `dd` to a flash drive/CD?

Comment: the osdev wiki has plenty of information available regarding this type of question. You'll probably find the [Bare bones](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones) "tutorial" interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "lost `stdio.h`", but many C runtime functions, including those prototyped in `stdio.h`, are implemented using system calls.  Without an OS running, those system calls won't work.

It is possible to write C code that runs without an OS, for example most common bootloaders have just a tiny amount of assembler and mostly C code.  The trick is to avoid using runtime libraries.  Alternatives to syscalls, for e.g. display, are BIOS calls and hardware-specific I/O.

To take just one example, in addition to dynamic allocation, `fopen` in read mode needs the following low-level operations:

- Reading a block of data from storage
- Reading the file system metadata (often, superblock and root directory)
- Processing file system metadata to find out where the file content is stored
- Creating a FILE object that contains enough information for `fread` and `fgetc` to find the data on disk

You don't have an OS to help with any of that, your C code will need to implement a driver (possibly calling the BIOS) for block read, and implement the behavior of the other steps.

Comment: Is it possible to create a Unix-like filesystem and store at least libc and all of it's files, and also important Unix system executables such as bash, cd, grep, and everything in the /bin folder?

Comment: @Mohit: You can store those binaries in a filesystem, but they won't *work*, since they depend on syscalls.  `libc` is very OS-specific.

Comment: Ok. So how would I combine the C and Assembler? I know to use "call", but how do I get my C files into the .bin?

Comment: @Mohit: You probably want to read about how a linker works.  Also programs like `elf2bin` (commonly found in the build system for bootloaders).